# Why doesn't @autoclosure @escaping on an async-function work and how to fix it

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency, queue

I have a queue for async-functions like so:

```
class Queue {
    var queue: [() async -> Void] = []
    
    func enqueue(_ operation: @escaping () async -> Void) {
        queue.append(operation)
    }
}
```

and you use it like this:

```
func networkCall() async {
    Task.sleep(2)
}

let queue = Queue()
queue.enque(networkCall)
```

I wanted a similar look for trying to enque a function with arguments like this:
`queue.enque(networkCall(duration: 2))`

To do this I have to add the `@autoclosure` attribute to the `enqueue(_:)` function like so:

```
func enqueue(_ operation: @autoclosure @escaping () async -> Void) {
    // ...
}
```

But this resulted in an error: `'async' autoclosure parameter in a non-'async' function`.

My question is, why does this error occur? The autoclosure is also escaping so it's not getting executed inside the enque function, so why does the compiler care that it's not marked with `async`? I also want to know if there is any fix to this so as to achieve a function call like `queue.enque(networkCall(duration: 2))` for my enqueue function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While yes, there is nothing *technically* wrong with an escaping async autoclosure as a parameter of a non-async function, Swift still prevents you from doing that because of "stylistic" reasons.

Think about how you would call `enqueue`. You *cannot* call it the way you'd like:

```
queue.enqueue(networkCall(duration: 2))
```

Instead, you need to do:

```
queue.enqueue(await networkCall(duration: 2))
```

Because one of the fundamental principles of Swift Concurrency is that all suspension points be marked with `await`, just like how every place where an error could occur is marked with `try`.

Try actually making `enqueue` async and see it for yourself - you must write

```
await queue.enqueue(await networkCall(duration: 2))
```

So if `enqueue` is not async, then that means something like `queue.enqueue(await networkCall(duration: 2))` could appear in non-async code. **You'd end up with `await` *seemingly* appearing in non-async code.** Of course, that's not true under the hood, but it still is surprising and requires readers to go to the definition of `enqueue` to see that it is actually an autoclosure.

In fact, [some people argue](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-make-autoclosure-and-escaping-mutually-exclusive/22678) that `@autoclosure` should not be used with `@escaping` at all (without anything async), because the automatically created closure could unexpectedly capture `self` and creates a retain cycle.

I'd suggest just take a non-auto closure. The syntax is just a matter of `()` vs `{}` anyway:

```
queue.enqueue { await networkCall(duration: 2) }
```

You would need the `await` whether or not this restriction is lifted or not.